# Basic connection and fetching from active directory

Tags: perl, active-directory, win32ole

I'm new to Perl and to Active Directory.
I need an example code of connecting into 
an Active Directory server 
(only address, there's no need to login), 
and fetch all the details of a user by id.

I've searched the net and found script only
with the use of Net::ldap, but I am forced 
to use Win32::Ole. Could someone please help
me to get it right at this way?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Net::Ldap. If you are not able to do so then the second best approach is to use some kind of Windows tool (like ldifde.exe/csvde.exe) and parse its output.

Basic usage: http://ss64.com/nt/csvde.html

More on ldifde: http://blogs.technet.com/b/lifeofapfe/archive/2009/02/19/using-ldifde-to-export-users-from-active-directory.aspx

Regards,

Comment: I am not allowed to use it, only win32::ole, and there is no info in the internet or any example how to use it with active directory in the way I've mentioned